# Using an If statement in JavaCC

Tags: javacc

I am pretty new to JavaCC, and I can't figure out how to create a conditional in a JavaCC grammar.

I have two tokens which are an ARROW ("->") and a RATE ("[*double*]"). In my grammar a RATE can go before, or after an ARROW.

How do I write the grammar to do basically this:

```
if nextToken is RATE:
    r = Rate()
else if nextToken is ARROW:
    ARROW
    r = Rate()
etc.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have done a little more reading and I think I need to use LOOKAHEAD.

Comment: Suggested edit: Perhaps there should be a line that says `ARROW` before the line that starts with `else if`.

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell in the psuedocode the ARROW token could be handled in the condintional or after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out an answer. I don't know if this is the best solution, but it is working.

I have:

```
(R = Rate() <ARROW>
| <ARROW> R = Rate())
```

Comment: That seems perfectly reasonable.  There is no need for an explicit lookahead. JavaCC will figure out which tokens can start a `Rate` and the first alternative will be taken if the next token is any of them.